# PHP: Given a multidimensional array convert it into single dimensional sorted, sort of

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Basically, I want to convert the below multidimensional array:

```
Array
(

[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => foo
        [1] => bar
        [2] => hello
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => world
        [1] => love
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => stack
        [1] => overflow
        [2] => yep
        [3] => man
    )
)
```

Into this:

```
Array
(
  [0] => foo
  [1] => world
  [2] => stack
  [3] => bar
  [4] => love
  [5] => overflow
  [6] => hello
  [7] => yep
  [8] => man
)
```

1. first element from first sub-array
2. first element from second sub-array, etc
3. second element from first sub-array
4. second element from second sub-array, etc...

Comment: Is the order important?

Comment: yes @Sven ! the order is very important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've had a couple beers and I'll try and tighten this up later, but this does the trick for integer indexed arrays:

```
$result = array();

for($i=0; $c=array_column($array, $i); $i++) {
    $result = array_merge($result, $c);
}
print_r($result);
```

- Loop getting an array of columns starting with column 0 and increment the column number.
- So long as there are columns, get an array of that column and merge with the result.

Comment: I do like the use of `array_column()` here.

Answer (score 0):

There is an often overlooked Iterator that will help you here: The MultipleIterator.

I have created some demo code: https://3v4l.org/beOMV

```
<?php

$arr = [
    0 => [
        0 => 'foo',
        1 => 'bar',
        2 => 'hello',
    ],
    1 => [
        0 => 'world',
        1 => 'love',
    ],
    2 => [
        0 => 'stack',
        1 => 'overflow',
        2 => 'yep',
        3 => 'man',
    ]
];

$parallelIterator = new MultipleIterator(MultipleIterator::MIT_NEED_ANY|MultipleIterator::MIT_KEYS_NUMERIC);

$parallelIterator->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($arr[0]));
$parallelIterator->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($arr[1]));
$parallelIterator->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($arr[2]));

$result = [];

foreach ($parallelIterator as $values) {
    foreach ($values as $value) {
        if ($value !== null) {
            $result[] = $value;
        }
    }    
}

var_dump($result);
```

Essentially, iterating over the MultipleIterator will give you an array with all the first entries (and then second and so on) of ALL attached iterators in parallel. By using either `MultipleIterator::MIT_NEED_ANY` or `MultipleIterator::MIT_NEED_ALL` you can decide that the loop should stop either when the last iterator has no more elements, or when the first iterator runs out of elements. When you run until the last element of the last iterator, you'll get NULL instead.

When attaching iterators, you can also add a key that will be used in the array when iterating, and have to uses `MultipleIterator::MIT_KEYS_ASSOC` - I have simply used numeric indices here because the source of the particular array was not interesting.

The result is

```
array(9) { 
    [0]=> string(3) "foo" 
    [1]=> string(5) "world" 
    [2]=> string(5) "stack" 
    [3]=> string(3) "bar" 
    [4]=> string(4) "love" 
    [5]=> string(8) "overflow" 
    [6]=> string(5) "hello" 
    [7]=> string(3) "yep" 
    [8]=> string(3) "man" 
}
```

Yes, you can iterate over that initial array when attaching the sub arrays to the MultipleIterator if you want:

```
foreach ($arr as $innerArr) {
    $parallelIterator->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($innerArr));
}
```